# Finding the 3rd point of a scalene triangle, with 2 points and a degree?

Tags: javascript, svg, trigonometry

I have an unfinished triangle, what I know are:

- coords for point A
- coords for point B
- length of AB

I'm trying to place a temporary point, on the same Y axis of B based on a given degree that will start with A. In the image below, I need to find where to plot `Temp C`, in order to make my line from AC be a specified degree.

[image]

I'm trying to do this with JS, but I keep running into a chicken before the egg situation, where I think I need to know the distance of BC to be able to plot AC's line.

`points` are the selection of 2 divs

```
<div class="center-point"></div>
<div class="center-point"></div>
```

```
const plotTempPoint = (points, deg, distance) => {
    const angle = deg * (Math.PI/180);
  const a = points[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const b = points[1].getBoundingClientRect();
    let c = {
    x: '',
    y:''
  };
  const angleAB = Math.atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x);
  if (deg > 0) {
    c.x = b.x + Math.cos(angleAB + angle)
    c.y = b.y + Math.sin(angleAB + angle)
  } else {
    c.x = b.x + Math.cos(angleAB - angle)
    c.y = b.y + Math.sin(angleAB - angle)
  }
  
    const coords = document.querySelector('.coords');
  const temp = document.createElement("div");
  temp.setAttribute('class', 'center-point temp');
  temp.style.top = `${c.y}px`;
  coords.appendChild(temp)
  
  return c.y;
}
```

This almost works, but it's based on the distance on AB, so when I plot C, it doesn't have the correct distance. So anything above 22deg, or below -22deg errors out.

Comment: If you know the coordinates of A and B, the length of `AB` is already determined, it shouldn't be an input.

Comment: Where do `p1` and `p2` come from?

Comment: Given the angle `BAC` you should be able to calculate where the line AC intersects the Y axis. This is the slope-intercept formula: y=mx+b.

Comment: @Barmar p1 is the (x,y) of A and p2 is the (x,y) of B

Comment: Why aren't they inputs to the function?

Comment: In my example I'm getting them with `querySelectorAll`, but I was more worried about trying to get the math correct, rather than the selections via JS. I'll update the question, 1 moment

Comment: Are A and B guaranteed to have the same Y coordinate, like in your picture? I.e. is it always a right triangle?

Comment: @Barmar, no, there could be situations where B is below or above A. but BC should always be directly inline.

Comment: Anyway, this really seems like a [math.se] question. Once you get the math right, converting it to JS should be straightforward.